# Odd behaviour for the update button when displaying a WP_List_Table

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, wp-update-post, wp-list-table

I am currently trying to add a WP_List_Table to a metabox in the edit page of a custom type. The code is currently

```
    class Post_Table extends WP_List_Table {

    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct([
            'singular' => __( 'Post', 'sp' ),
            'plural'   => __( 'Posts', 'sp' ),
            'ajax'     => false 
        ]);
    }

    function get_columns(){
        $columns = array(
        'cb'    => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'title' => 'Title',
        );
        return $columns;
    }

    function prepare_items() {
        $columns = $this->get_columns();
        $hidden = array();
        $sortable = array();
        $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);
        $this->items = array();
    }

    function add_item($item)
    {
        array_push($this->items, $item);
    }

    function column_default( $item, $column_name ) {
        switch( $column_name ) { 
            case 'title':
                return $item[ $column_name ];
            default:
                return print_r( $item, true ) ; 
      }
    }

    function column_title($item) {
        $actions = array(
            'delete'    => sprintf('<a >Delete</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'delete',$item['ID']),
        );

        return sprintf('%1$s %2$s', $item['title'], $this->row_actions($actions) );
    }
    function get_bulk_actions() {
        $actions = array(
            'delete'    => 'Delete'
        );
        return $actions;
    }

    function process_bulk_action() {        
        if( 'delete'===$this->current_action() ) 
        {
            update_post_meta($post->ID, '_page_list', array());
        }        
    }

    function column_cb($item) {
        return sprintf(
            '<input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="%s" />', $item['ID']
        );    
    }


}

$postTable = new Post_Table();
$postTable->prepare_items(); 
$n = 1;

foreach($page_list as $page)
{
    $postTable->add_item(array(
        'ID' => $n,
        'title' => get_the_title(get_post($page))
        ));
    $n++;
}

//$postTable->display();
```

If I uncomment $postTable->display(), the update button of the edit page ceases to work correctly. It does not save changes anymore, and instead just redirects me to wp-admin/edit.php, the list of all posts. This behaviour still remains if I comment out all action-related methods in the Post_Table class.

What causes this behaviour and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing to do with the class itself - you are using the reserved input name `post`, which is conflicting with WordPress core:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="%s" />
```

Change it something unique to your theme/plugin e.g. `name="my_plugin_ids[]"`

Comment: Changing the name or commenting out that function still produces the same problem.

Comment: Hmm, must be one of the other inputs that `WP_List_Table` kicks out (methods called by `display` e.g. `display_tablenav`). List table class was never really designed to be used on an edit post page.

Comment: What would be a good alternative to put a list in a custom metabox?

Comment: Based on what it looks like you're trying to do, I would just output an HTML table with PHP, using core WordPress classes for styling e.g. `<table class="widefat fixed striped"><thead>...</thead><tbody>...</tbody></table>`